# Calculate $\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty(2^{2^{(-i)}}-1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, exponentiation

> Calculate $\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty(2^{2^{(-i)}}-1)$

By a Python program showed below, I can calculate that it is about $1.7818$($1.7818386318393353172743493971315840477111345642771002580086952600435098253141880734976160498115058888973$ by a comment). I've worked on this problem for days, but I can't solve it. Can anyone help me?

**Update:** I'm a student who is interested in math. I came out with this problem about one year ago, but I think it's too difficult for me.

Also, $2^{2^{(-i)}}-1\le2^{(-i)}$, so it is a convergent serie.

**Update 2:** Why $2^{2^{(-i)}}-1\le2^{(-i)}$?
Let $x$ be $2^{(-i)}$, $i\ge0$, so $x\ge1$, then $2^{2^{(-i)}}-1-2^{(-i)}=2^x-1-x$.
When $x=1$, $2^x-1-x=0$, and $\frac{d(2^x-1-x)}{dx}=2^x\ln-1>0$ for $x\ge1$, so $2^{2^{(-i)}}-1-2^{(-i)}=2^x-1-x>0$, that means $2^{2^{(-i)}}-1\le2^{(-i)}$.

**Update 5 on 2021-07-02: Anyone who can show whether the sum is rational can win the bounty.**

```
from math import *
s = 0
a = 2
while a != 1:
    s += a - 1
    a = sqrt(a)
print(s)
```

Comment: For purposes of context, please provide (1) The source of this question (What made you work on this question? Interest? Assignment? Part of a bigger problem?) (2) If need be, please include the program you have written : if it is small enough, then include it as text, otherwise a link to it would be great. Coming to your question itself, have you been able to prove that it is a convergent sequence, at least?

Comment: It seems unlikely that there is a closed form for this sum.

Comment: Perfect, I noticed the edits. Thank you once again, and +1 from my side.

Comment: I can give you more digits:  [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum+2%5E%282%5E%28-n%29%29-1+from+0+to+infinity) gives $1.7818386318393353172743493971315840477111345642771002580086952600435098253141880734976160498115058888973$ and you can click on more digits if you want.  The fact that it doesn't give a closed form says it is not easy to find one.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Can you swear by each of the digits that "Alpha" gives? I doubt it. In any case, I agree that it is unlikely that a closed formula exists.

Comment: @Oliver Diaz: PARI/GP gives the same output.

Comment: @g.kov: I don'r doubt that with good multi precision algorithms you can get the 10^10 first digits with just a smartphone. the things is that once convergence has been established for this series (which by the looks of it, converges very fast) a simple double recision calculation in Fortran77 (or Python for that matter)
 would give you a decent approximation. The OP was asking for closed form, which very likely does not exists in terms of well known functions. So what is the point of producing 50 "significant" digits.

Comment: @Oliver Diaz: Yes, I agree that most probably there is no closed form for that sum.
But sarcasm (as in "significant") is inappropriate here.

Comment: @Alex-Github-Programmer: If you know that the series converges, and in fact converges very fast, numerical methods suffice to get more than descent approximation. Notice the you can bound your series $S$: $2\log(2)\leq S\leq 2\frac{2^{2^0}-1}{2^0}$ the check that you computer estimation is "fine". Your series is almost geometric so convergence is fast.

Comment: @OliverDiaz What do you mean with "Can you swear by each of the digits that "Alpha" gives? " ? We use software to make this kind of calculations. Have you ever computed BY HAND the first 6 digits of $\pi$? Can you swear they are $3.141592\ldots $? I don't see the point in your comment. I also think (as g.kov) that sarcasm in the other comment is inappropiate.

Comment: @jjagmath: who is "we"? I know that there are very interesting algorithms that can give you billions (if not more) of exact digits of $\pi$. They are important and use as benchmarks for computer speed. But back to OP, how showing Mathematica estimates (or PARI, or Fortran77 multiple precision algorithms) solve the OP? His Python code will give (in double) precision 16 (or so) digits that are kosher. That is because the series converges very fast. Seeing that has more value that running things in Alpha and spitting out digits.

Comment: You could define $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \left(x^{2^{-i}}-1\right)$ and study properties of $f(x)$.  E.g., $f(1) = 0$ and $f(x^2) = f(x)+x^2-1$.  Taking derivatives of the functional equation gives you a Taylor series expansion at $x=1$.  But I don't think this will lead to anything enlightening about $f(2)$.  On the other hand, this reminds me of the interesting problem #8 at http://people.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/Misc/index.html.

Comment: @OliverDiaz How do you know there are 50 "significant" digits in Rossmillikan's number? Did you count it? :)

Comment: Because $\ln(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{x^h-1}{h}$ we can approximate the end behavior of the sum for large $n$ as,

$$\sum_{i=n}^\infty 2^{2^{-i}}-1 \approx\sum_{i=n}^\infty 2^{-i} \ln(2)=\frac{\ln(4)}{2^n}$$

Comment: @NN2: who cares? Look at robjohn's answer; he did an excellent job in producing a representation of the series that sets to converge even faster.

Comment: @OlivierDiaz what relevance concerning the answer? I already gave him 2 upvotes (one for the answer and one for his comment next to my comment). It’s you who helped him to write his answer? $$$$ PS: He showed 40 digits in his answer! :)

Comment: Your sum also equals $$-1+\lim_{N\to \infty} -N+\sum_{n=0}^N 2^{2^{-n}}$$ as seen [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/t0cupm6xrm)

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is a closed form for this sum, but it can be rewritten to converge even more quickly
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(2^{2^{-k}}-1\right)
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(e^{\log(2)\,2^{-k}}-1\right)\tag1\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\log(2)\,2^{-k}\right)^j}{j!}\tag2\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{\log(2)^j}{j!}\left(1+\frac1{2^j-1}\right)\tag3\\
&=1+\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{\log(2)^j}{j!}\frac1{2^j-1}\tag4\\[6pt]
&=1.7818386318393353172743493971315840477111\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $2=e^{\log(2)}$
$(2)$: use the series for $e^x-1$
$(3)$: sum the geometric series in $k$
$(4)$: recognize the series for $e^{\log(2)}-1=1$
$(5)$: evaluate to $40$ places

The number of digits for $n$ terms of the original series is
$$
n\log_{10}(2)+O(1)\sim n\log_{10}(2)\tag6
$$
whereas the number of digits for $n$ terms of the series in $(4)$ is
$$
\left(n+\frac12\right)\log_{10}\left(\frac{2n}{e\log(2)}\right)+O(1)\sim n\log_{10}(n)\tag7
$$
and it is easy to see that $(7)$ grows faster than $(6)$.

Comment: I put this approximation through the [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html) and got nothing.

Comment: I also found the general formula $$(a-1)+\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{\log(a)^j}{j!}\frac1{a^j-1}$$ However, how do you know this representation converges more quickly (than the initial representation)?

Comment: The terms of the initial representation are approximately $\log(2)2^{-j}$, whereas the terms of the series in this answer are approximately $\log(2)^j2^{-j}/j!$. Both the $\log(2)^j$ and the $1/j!$ contribute to the faster convergence (especially the $1/j!$).

Comment: Just for the fun $$e+\frac 1{1000}\Big[e^{\pi } J_0(1)\Big]^{e^{\frac 1e}}-1=1.7818386$$ in absolute error of $2.16\times 10^{-8}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici How did you find that?

Comment: @robjohn It might be worth noting that via Abel-Plana
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty }{{{2}^{{{2}^{-n}}}}-1}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\alpha }\left\{ E{{i}_{1}}\left( \alpha  \right)-\gamma -\log \left( \alpha  \right) \right\}+2\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }{\frac{{{e}^{\alpha \cos \left( \alpha t \right)}}\sin \left( \alpha \sin \left( \alpha t \right) \right)}{{{e}^{2\pi t}}-1}dt}$$
The integral can be completed via a series which yields your result.  Not sure if anything further can be squeezed from this though.

Comment: @mathstackuser12: Thanks for the analysis. This rate of convergence is pretty good and, although I don't see an easy way to accelerate further, I can't say it's impossible.